# MEAN Stack Auth - Can't register new user with Mlab/Heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku, mlab

I have a working auth on a local project, but am trying to deploy it with Heroku and Mlab.  I can post new objects, but cannot get my Auth to work. I am not sure why. I am using the MEAN stack with Angular 1.6.

[Github](https://github.com/kenny-vo/badger-projectv3)

[Heroku Project](https://identifly.herokuapp.com/#/register)

This is how I am currently posting new objects to the hosted database.

```
var VENDORS_COLLECTION = "vendors";
var USERS_COLLECTION = "users";

// Create a database variable outside of the database connection 
callback to reuse the connection pool in your app.
var db;

// Connect to the database before starting the application server.
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, function (err, 
database) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // Save database object from the callback for reuse.
  db = database;
  console.log("Database connection ready");

  // Initialize the app.
  var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
     var port = server.address().port;
     console.log("App now running on port", port);
  });
});



app.post("/vendors", function(req, res) {
  var newVendor = req.body;
  newVendor.createDate = new Date();

  db.collection(VENDORS_COLLECTION).insertOne(newVendor, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
     handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new vendor.");
    } else {
     res.status(201).json(doc.ops[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

This is how my auth works locally:

```
app.post('/auth/signup', function (req, res) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, existingUser) {
  if (existingUser) {
    return res.status(409).send({ message: 'Email is already taken.' });
  }
  var user = new User({
    displayName: req.body.displayName,
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  user.save(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    }
      res.send({ token: auth.createJWT(result) });
    });
   });
  });
```

Tried to refactor to look like this but no luck.

```
    app.post('/auth/signup', function (req, res) {
     db.collection(USERS_COLLECTION).findOne...
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Not getting any errors.

Comment: Do err or doc equal anything in your mongo callback?